# sorting a 2d list based on number of elements in each list (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have this list in python:

```
[[153, 154], [2009, 2010, 2011], [3858, 3859, 3860], [5689, 5690]]
```

is there a way to sort the list based on the number of elements in each list so that this would be the result:

```
[[2009, 2010, 2011],[3858, 3859, 3860],[153, 154], [5689, 5690]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In python2 you can do the following:

```
my_list = [[153, 154], [2009, 2010, 2011], [3858, 3859, 3860], [5689, 5690]]
sorted(k, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
sorted(items,key=len, reverse=True)
```

where `items` is your list